# How to render only js without html (template, layout) in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render, erb

I have controller Message_Controller and this Controller has method "message" in this method i wanna render .js.erb file i need call js function from rails controller.I need reneder it without html-template(layout) just only js-code in this code i will call js-function with args .How to make it ??

My routes:

```
 post 'chat_bot/message', to: 'chat_bot#message'
```

My controller:

```
class ChatBotController < ApplicationController
     layout false

    def message
         #gon.watch.message = params[:text]
        @message = params[:text]
            puts @message
        render partial: 'message.js.erb', layout: false
    end


end
```

my message.js.erb file

```
alert('<%=@message %>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
render partial: 'message.js.erb', layout: false
```

Rails is going to look for a partial called _message.js.erb right in the folder responding to that controller.

You can use `respond_to` and there specify the format and what to render:

```
def message
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render partial: 'message.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

You can skip the instance variable assignation if you prefer, as you have access to the params within the request.

If your idea is to "evaluate" the alert, then it still should be inside a script tag:

```
<script>
  alert("<%= params[:text] %>");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thx. It works. But  when i use render then open new page "/chat_bot/message". How to call a function from the controller without opening a new page?

Comment: You can make a JSON request.

Answer (score 0):

just update it with

```
def message
  @message = params[:text]
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: How to call a function from the controller without opening a new page?

Comment: make a ajax call with dataType: "script"